# Angular nested directives with isolate scope - form input

Tags: angularjs, input, nested, angularjs-scope, directive

I am trying to get to grips with directives and am struggling with one aspect. The expression in the form input element of a directive is not being evaluated when used in an attribute which is also a directive.

Consider this element which is part of the directives HTML,

```
<input name="atin" type="text" ng-model="model" required="{{req}}" random-attribute="{{req}}"/>
```

Assuming the value of the attribute value "req" (passed in via an isolate scope attribute) is "true",   then when the directive has been compiled/linked the resultant HTML (when you view the source) is

```
<input name="atin" type="text" ng-model="model" required="{{req}}" random-attribute="true"/>
```

I.e. it has only been substituted in the "random-attribute", but not the "required" attribute. I am guessing this has something to do with the fact that the required attribute is itself a directive.

Here is a plunkr which demonstrates it

http://plnkr.co/edit/sq5lpbKqjyV9mCOwSBTo

I do know of one solution which involves adding the input elements attributes during the compile stage of the atInput directive, but I would like to know why this current solution does not work and what is the best way to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need to do `ng-required="req"` instead of `required="{{req}}"`...